# How to copy table from one database to other database in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two databases, **`test1`** & **`test2`**. In **`test1`** there is a table attendence, I want to copy this attendece table in database **`test2`**. I am writing following code:

```
CREATE TABLE test1.attendence SELECT * FROM test2.attendence;
```

But it gives the error:

```
--Table 'test2.attendence' doesn't exist
```

So please provide a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

insert into table2 select * from table1

or if they dont have the same structure:

insert into table2 (col, col2, col5) select (x,y,z) from table1

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE x LIKE other_db.y;

INSERT INTO x SELECT * FROM other_db.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

you're almost there :)

but you want to create the new table in test2, so, the correct command should be

```
CREATE TABLE test2.attendence LIKE test1.attendence;
INSERT INTO test2.attendence SELECT * FROM test1.attendence;
```